# Option Inspector, cannot expand navigation pane

Tags: front-end, windows

The navigation pane in the Option Inspector is too small and I can find no way to make it larger:

[image: option inspector]

Is there any way to enlarge it?

Comment: This question is OS dependent (the Option Inspector looks very different in OS X, for example), Please mark it as such by tagging it with the appropriate OS tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows the vertical divider between the two vertical panes of the options inspector is movable, even though the mouse pointer does not change to a double headed arrow when hovering over it as one would expect. However, if you click-and-drag it, you can resize those panes at will.

[image]

Comment: Aha, that would explain it. The mouse does not change when you hover over the bar so I thought it did not work, but actually it does.